# Setting a delegate to an outlet in a class without an initialiser

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to assign a delegate to a pickerView outlet in a class with a UITableViewCell protocol.

My application is rather basic, it has an usual UIViewController class

```
class ADScreen: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

with an extension

```
extension ADScreen: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
(...) 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tag")!
            return cell
(...)
}
```

As you can see, I am populating the table with custom cells.

```
class TTViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
(...)
}

extension TTViewCell: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
(...)
}
```

The problem is that the class of  the cell also has a UIPickerView outlet that I would like to populate, but can't because I have no initialiser to put the `pickerView.delegate = self` line in, and I'm not sure where do I put it in this case. I've tried to create a custom `init()` function but it got really complicated over time and wouldn't work anyway with my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use override method awakeFromNib() to initialize any properties.

```
class TTViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        pickerView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension TTViewCell: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 10 // set number of components
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 5 // set number of rows
    }
}
```

Check this code.